# Multi-store: Product image (default) import, base, small, thumbnail images are not setting in (non-default) store

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I have multi-website instance. I imported product images via Magento2 (default) tool under admin->system->import....

The images imported successfully, and I can see, each imported image set as base, small and thumbnail, under product (default) store.

However, if I switch to another store via (Store View), the image exists, but did not set as base, small and thumbnail.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please confirm your OS, like Windows or Ubuntu?

If uploading CSV from Ubuntu, then please re-import via Windows.

Sometimes, import makes issue due to the OS.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, previously, I was uploading via Ubuntu, now imported via Windows and it rocks. Thanks....